# How select several child panel like grid in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, calendar, grid, mouse, rows

Actually I have a datagrid and Panel (Simulating a grid) in Winforms for simulating the days of month, the idea is to select with the mouse cursor the rows (left to right) and count the numbers of Row, then put on an object control (Panel, Textbox, Label... whatever ) with a name person.

I don't know which one is the best alternative, if I use a datagrid or panel,
if it exists other alternatives please help me, to create this.

Example:

http://s.mcstatic.com/thumb/9974164/26063679/4/flash_player/0/1/hotelogix_tutorial_housekeeping.jpg

Comment: Use a Calendar control, available online in many places.